# Parse large python xml using xmltree

Tags: python, xml, grep, lxml, elementtree

I have a python script that parses huge xml files ( largest one is 446 MB)

```
    try:
        parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8')
        tree = etree.parse(os.path.join(srcDir, fileName), parser)
        root = tree.getroot()
    except Exception, e:
        print "Error parsing file "+str(fileName) + " Reason "+str(e.message)

    for child in root:
        if "PersonName" in child.tag:
            personName = child.text
```

This is what my xml looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyRoot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" uuid="ertr" xmlns="http://www.example.org/yml/data/litsmlv2">
  <Aliases authority="OPP" xmlns="http://www.example.org/yml/data/commonv2">
     <Description>myData</Description>
     <Identifier>43hhjh87n4nm</Identifier>
  </Aliases>
  <RollNo uom="kPa">39979172.201167159</RollNo>
  <PersonName>Miracle Smith</PersonName>
  <Date>2017-06-02T01:10:32-05:00</Date>
....
```

All I want to do is get the PersonName tags contents thats all. Other tags I don't care about.

Sadly My files are huge and I keep getting this error when I use the code above :

```
Error parsing file 2eb6d894-0775-e611.xml Reason unknown error, line 1, column 310915857
Error parsing file 2ecc18b5-ef41-e711-80f.xml Reason Extra content at the end of the document, line 1, column 3428182
Error parsing file 2f0d6926-b602-e711-80f4-005.xml Reason Extra content at the end of the document, line 1, column 6162118
Error parsing file 2f12636b-b2f5-e611-80f3-00.xml Reason Extra content at the end of the document, line 1, column 8014679
Error parsing file 2f14e35a-d22b-4504-8866-.xml Reason Extra content at the end of the document, line 1, column 8411238
Error parsing file 2f50c2eb-55c6-e611-80f0-005056a.xml Reason Extra content at the end of the document, line 1, column 7636614
Error parsing file 3a1a3806-b6af-e611-80ef-00505.xml Reason Extra content at the end of the document, line 1, column 11032486
```

My XML is perfectly fine and has no extra content .Seems that the large files parsing causes the error. 
I have looked at iterparse() but it seems to complex for what I want to achieve as it provides parsing of the whole DOM while I just want that one tag that is under the root. Also , does not give me a good sample to get the correct value by tag name ?

Should I use a regex parse or grep /awk way to do this ? Or any tweak to my code will let me get the Person name in these huge files ?

**UPDATE:**
Tried this sample and it seems to be printing the whole world from the xml except my tag ?

Does iterparse read from bottom to top of file ? In that case it will take a long time to get to the top i.e my PersonName Tag ? I tried changing the line below to read end to start  events=("end", "start")     and it does the same thing !!!

```
path = []
for event, elem in ET.iterparse('D:\\mystage\\2-80ea-005056.xml', events=("start", "end")):
    if event == 'start':
            path.append(elem.tag)
    elif event == 'end':
            # process the tag
            print elem.text  // prints whole world 
            if elem.tag == 'PersonName':
                print elem.text
            path.pop()
```

Comment: If you don't need to navigate the structure of the xml (you don't care what the parent of the tag is for instance) and you only care about this entry, then regex is probably a better solution. If all your cases are like the example you posted you could even do something very lazy like: matches = [line for line in open('myfile', 'r') if line.strip().startswith('<PersonName>')]. That is assuming that your xml file lines are split with a newline as in your example.

Comment: Thanks !I will try that out.  An xml solution would also be good to consider keeping the future in mind .

Comment: Yes, if this is going to become more complex it probably makes sense to invest the time to understand how iterparse works. I think I used it for wikipedia dumps at some point and it was a bit harder to use but worth it in the end.

Comment: @AndreasGrivas each file has only one line, as seen from the errors `line 1, column ######`. I would do a regex with `(?<=<PersonName>)[^<]*(?=</PersonName>)`, ofcourse with no reliability on working if the structure changes.

Comment: @bulbus good point, missed that, thanks. Regex to the rescue :)

Comment: added some stuff my attempts using iterparse

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/  I think im getting there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterparse is not that difficult to use in this case.

`temp.xml` is the file presented in your question with a `</MyRoot>` stuck on as a line at the end.

Think of the `source =` as boilerplace, if you will, that parses the xml file and returns chunks of it element-by-element, indicating whether the chunk is the 'start' of an element or the 'end' and supplying information about the element.

In this case we need consider only the 'start' events. We watch for the 'PersonName' tags and pick up their texts. Having found the one and only such item in the xml file we abandon the processing.

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree
>>> source = iter(ElementTree.iterparse('temp.xml', events=('start', 'end')))
>>> for an_event, an_element in source:
...     if an_event=='start' and an_element.tag.endswith('PersonName'):
...         an_element.text
...         break
... 
'Miracle Smith'
```

Edit, in response to question in a comment:

Normally you wouldn't do this since `iterparse` is intended for use with large chunks of xml. However, by wrapping a string in a `StringIO` object it can be processed with `iterparse`.

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> xml = StringIO('''\
... <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
... <MyRoot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" uuid="ertr" xmlns="http://www.example.org/yml/data/litsmlv2">
...   <Aliases authority="OPP" xmlns="http://www.example.org/yml/data/commonv2">
...        <Description>myData</Description>
...             <Identifier>43hhjh87n4nm</Identifier>
...               </Aliases>
...                 <RollNo uom="kPa">39979172.201167159</RollNo>
...                   <PersonName>Miracle Smith</PersonName>
...                     <Date>2017-06-02T01:10:32-05:00</Date>
... </MyRoot>''')
>>> source = iter(ElementTree.iterparse(xml, events=('start', 'end')))
>>> for an_event, an_element in source:
...     if an_event=='start' and an_element.tag.endswith('PersonName'):
...         an_element.text
...         break
...     
'Miracle Smith'
```

Comment: Beautiful !! I doff my hat to you sir . I would also like to understand the error message here :  Extra content at the end of the document, when there is actually no extra content in my file ?!

Comment: When I have seen that it was as little as an extra blank or new-line. (I would doff my hat in return but I'm bald. :)

Comment: Just noticed mistake in second sentence and corrected it.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing on a string ?

Comment: just in case someone needs to read using a variable  that has the XML string, then u pass unicode(variable) to the StringIO method

Comment: @JakeSlattery: I'm afraid I don't understand.

Comment: I am sorry sir . Was just telling people to use :

Comment: source = iter(ElementTree.iterparse(StringIO(unicode(xml_string)), events=('start', 'end')))

Comment: @JakeSlattery: No apology necessary! Simply didn't understand. Thanks for responding.