# XML to CSV using xml.etree.ElementTree.interparse functionality

Tags: python, xml, csv

Folks, I am new (brand new) to python, so after taking a course I decided to create a script to covert an XML file to CSV.  The file in question is 2GB in size, so after searching here and on google I think I need to use the xml.etree.ElementTree.interparse functionality.  For reference the XML file I am looking to covert looks like this:

```
<Document>
  <type></type>
  <internal_id></internal_id>
  <name></name>
  <number></number>
  <cadname></cadname>
  <version></version>
  <iteration></iteration>
  **<isLatest></isLatest>**
  <modifiedBy>
     <username></username>
     <email/>
  </modifiedBy>
  <content>
     **<name></name>**
     <id></id>
     <uploaded></uploaded>
     <refSize></refSize>
     <storage>
        <vault></vault>
        <folder></folder>
        **<filename></filename>**
        <location></location>
        **<actualLocation></actualLocation>**
     </storage>
     <replicatedTo></replicatedTo>
     <copies></copies>
     <status></status>
  </content>
```

I am using the value of isLatest to determine whether I need to add the items to the CSV file.  If the value is "true" I want the data to move to the CSV file.  Here is the code that works to a point:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

parser = ET.iterparse("windchill.xml")

# open a file for writing

csvfile = open('windchill.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8")

# create the csv writer object

csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
count = 0
for event, document in parser:

if document.tag == 'Document':
    if document.find('isLatest').text == 'true':
        row = []
        name = document.find('content').find('name').text
        row.append(name)
        filename = document.find('content').find('storage').find('filename').text
        row.append(filename)
        folder = document.find('content').find('storage').find('actualLocation').text
        row.append(folder)
        csvwriter.writerow(row)
        document.clear()
csvfile.close()
```

If I run the code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mike/PycharmProjects/windchill/xml2csv-stream.py", line 17, in <module>
if document.find('isLatest').text == 'true':
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

A file is created that has 91,000 entries that look like this:

```
plate.prt,000000000518e8,/vault/Vlt7
adhesive.prt,0000000005024b,/vault/Vlt7
brd_pad.prt,00000000057862,/vault/Vlt7
support_pad.prt,0000000005024c,/vault/Vlt7
ground.prt,0000000005089b,/vault/Vlt7
```

There seem to be two issues with the output.

1. Some items seem to be duplicated, although the source file has no duplications.  The name could be duplicated in the source file, but there can only be one name value that is .
2. I don't think the file completed.  I looked at the last entry of my TXT (CSV) file and it does not match the last line of my source file.  I was assuming the iterator was serial in nature.

So, any idea what the error is telling me, and any idea why I may be seeing duplicates?  Originally I thought the error may have been related to me not ending gracefully.  I am confident the XML is formed properly throughout, but maybe that is a bad assumption.

******UPDATES******

Here is a sample of the elements.

```
<Document>
  <type>wt.epm.EPMDocument</type>
  <internal_id>33709881</internal_id>
  <name>bga_13x11p137_0_4_0_8.prt</name>
  <number>BGA_13X11P137_0_4_0_8.PRT</number>
  <cadname>bga_13x11p137_0_4_0_8.prt</cadname>
  <version>A</version>
  <iteration>1</iteration>
  <isLatest>false</isLatest>
  <modifiedBy>
     <username>ets027 (deleted)</username>
     <email/>
  </modifiedBy>
  <content>
     <name>bga_13x11p137_0_4_0_8.prt</name>
     <id>5341368</id>
     <uploaded>Jan 13, 2006 09:14:41</uploaded>
     <refSize>287764</refSize>
     <storage>
        <vault>master_vault</vault>
        <folder>master_vault7</folder>
        <filename>000000000505a6</filename>
        <location>[wt.fv.FvItem:33709835]::master::master_vault::master_vault7::000000000505a6</location>
        <actualLocation>/vault/Windchill_Vaults/WcVlt7</actualLocation>
     </storage>
     <replicatedTo>
     </replicatedTo>
     <copies>
     </copies>
     <status>Content File Missing</status>
  </content>
</Document>
<Document>
  <type>wt.epm.EPMDocument</type>
  <internal_id>34570129</internal_id>
  <name>d61-2446-02_nest_plate.prt</name>
  <number>D61-2446-02_NEST_PLATE.PRT</number>
  <cadname>d61-2446-02_nest_plate.prt</cadname>
  <version>-</version>
  <iteration>1</iteration>
  <isLatest>true</isLatest>
  <modifiedBy>
     <username>esb044c (deleted)</username>
     <email/>
  </modifiedBy>
  <content>
     <name>d61-2446-02_nest_plate.prt</name>
     <id>5344204</id>
     <uploaded>Jan 30, 2006 09:09:24</uploaded>
     <refSize>109278</refSize>
     <storage>
        <vault>master_vault</vault>
        <folder>master_vault7</folder>
        <filename>000000000518e8</filename>
        <location>[wt.fv.FvItem:34566594]::master::master_vault::master_vault7::000000000518e8</location>
        <actualLocation>/vault/Windchill_Vaults/WcVlt7</actualLocation>
     </storage>
     <replicatedTo>
     </replicatedTo>
     <copies>
     </copies>
     <status>Content File Missing</status>
  </content>
</Document>
<Document>
  <type>wt.epm.EPMDocument</type>
  <internal_id>33512036</internal_id>
  <name>d68-2568-07_press_head_adhesive.prt</name>
  <number>D68-2568-07_PRESS_HEAD_ADHESIVE.PRT</number>
  <cadname>d68-2568-07_press_head_adhesive.prt</cadname>
  <version>-</version>
  <iteration>2</iteration>
  <isLatest>true</isLatest>
  <modifiedBy>
     <username>e3789c (deleted)</username>
     <email/>
  </modifiedBy>
  <content>
     <name>d68-2568-07_press_head_adhesive.prt</name>
     <id>5340927</id>
     <uploaded>Jan 10, 2006 15:42:31</uploaded>
     <refSize>76314</refSize>
     <storage>
        <vault>master_vault</vault>
        <folder>master_vault7</folder>
        <filename>0000000005024b</filename>
        <location>[wt.fv.FvItem:33512072]::master::master_vault::master_vault7::0000000005024b</location>
        <actualLocation>/vault/Windchill_Vaults/WcVlt7</actualLocation>
     </storage>
     <replicatedTo>
     </replicatedTo>
     <copies>
     </copies>
     <status>Content File Missing</status>
  </content>
</Document>
<Document>
  <type>wt.epm.EPMDocument</type>
  <internal_id>34715717</internal_id>
  <name>dbk_flip_sleeve.prt</name>
  <number>DBK_FLIP_SLEEVE.PRT</number>
  <cadname>dbk_flip_sleeve.prt</cadname>
  <version>-</version>
  <iteration>1</iteration>
  <isLatest>false</isLatest>
  <modifiedBy>
     <username>EKA014 (deleted)</username>
     <email/>
  </modifiedBy>
  <content>
     <name>dbk_flip_sleeve.prt</name>
     <id>5344969</id>
     <uploaded>Feb 01, 2006 12:54:43</uploaded>
     <refSize>847210</refSize>
     <storage>
        <vault>master_vault</vault>
        <folder>master_vault7</folder>
        <filename>00000000051b54</filename>
        <location>[wt.fv.FvItem:34714395]::master::master_vault::master_vault7::00000000051b54</location>
        <actualLocation>/vault/Windchill_Vaults/WcVlt7</actualLocation>
     </storage>
     <replicatedTo>
     </replicatedTo>
     <copies>
     </copies>
     <status>Content File Missing</status>
  </content>
 </Document>
```

Here is my updated code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

parser = ET.iterparse("windchill.xml", events=('start', 'end'))

csvfile = open('windchill.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8")

csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)

for event, document in parser:

if event=='end' and document.tag=='Document':
    if document.find('type').text == 'wt.epm.EPMDocument' and document.find('isLatest').text == 'true':
        row = []
        version = document.find('version').text
        row.append(version)
        name = document.find('content').find('name').text
        row.append(name)
        filename = document.find('content').find('storage').find('filename').text
        row.append(filename)
#            folder = document.find('content').find('storage').find('actualLocation').text
        folder = document.find('content').find('storage').find('folder').text
        row.append(folder)
        csvwriter.writerow(row)

csvfile.close()
```

I added in a check for type.  Type wt.ep.EPMDocument will have the  record.  I then want to pull the data out of the storage element.  Specifically name, folder, and filename.  I originally was using actualLocation instead ov vault, but changed hoping the shorter name would help with my memory error.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your first issue: `iterparse` 'sees' each and every xml element in a document when that element starts and, again, when it closes. This probably explains the duplication that you find. Not only must you filter for the element(s) that you want, you must filter for the appropriate event. You might look at this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46167799/131187, to see how to deal with this.

Concerning the second: When `document.find('isLatest')` fails to find what you've requested it returns `None`, rather than an object representing an xml element. `None` has no properties, including `text`, therefore, your program croaks at that point, and you receive an incomplete csv file.

---

Edit in answer to comment: This code parses the xml but does not write the csv. csv records would be written in the `save_csv_record` function, or its equivalent. It appears only once in the code so should be easy to replace.

Called in the way it is in this code `iterparse` returns only 'end' events and their corresponding xml elements. Therefore, the code watches for the 'end' of a 'Document'. When it sees one it asks whether the document contains an 'isLatest' of 'true'. If it does it writes it out; if not, it ignores it and empties `document_content`. If the code has not seen the 'end' of a document it simply saves the content of the tag and keeps reading under it does.

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import iterparse

def save_csv_record(record):
    print(record)
    return

document_content = {}
for ev, el in iterparse('windchill.xml'):
    if el.tag=='Document':
        if document_content['isLatest'] == 'true':
            save_csv_record(document_content)
        document_content = {}
    else:
        document_content[el.tag] = el.text.strip() if el.text else None
```

Output:

```
{'folder': 'master_vault7', 'storage': '', 'refSize': '109278', 'cadname': 'd61-2446-02_nest_plate.prt', 'filename': '000000000518e8', 'replicatedTo': '', 'status': 'Content File Missing', 'number': 'D61-2446-02_NEST_PLATE.PRT', 'location': '[wt.fv.FvItem:34566594]::master::master_vault::master_vault7::000000000518e8', 'vault': 'master_vault', 'uploaded': 'Jan 30, 2006 09:09:24', 'id': '5344204', 'actualLocation': '/vault/Windchill_Vaults/WcVlt7', 'name': 'd61-2446-02_nest_plate.prt', 'modifiedBy': '', 'email': None, 'content': '', 'internal_id': '34570129', 'iteration': '1', 'username': 'esb044c (deleted)', 'type': 'wt.epm.EPMDocument', 'copies': '', 'isLatest': 'true', 'version': '-'}
{'folder': 'master_vault7', 'storage': '', 'refSize': '76314', 'cadname': 'd68-2568-07_press_head_adhesive.prt', 'filename': '0000000005024b', 'replicatedTo': '', 'status': 'Content File Missing', 'number': 'D68-2568-07_PRESS_HEAD_ADHESIVE.PRT', 'location': '[wt.fv.FvItem:33512072]::master::master_vault::master_vault7::0000000005024b', 'vault': 'master_vault', 'uploaded': 'Jan 10, 2006 15:42:31', 'id': '5340927', 'actualLocation': '/vault/Windchill_Vaults/WcVlt7', 'name': 'd68-2568-07_press_head_adhesive.prt', 'modifiedBy': '', 'email': None, 'content': '', 'internal_id': '33512036', 'iteration': '2', 'username': 'e3789c (deleted)', 'type': 'wt.epm.EPMDocument', 'copies': '', 'isLatest': 'true', 'version': '-'}
```

EDITED FOR LATEST CODE:

Here is the new code that I am using, that sill runs out of memory:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import iterparse

def save_csv_record(record):
 print(record)
 return

document_content = {}
for ev, el in iterparse('windchill.xml'):
if el.tag=='Document':
    if document_content['type']=='wt.epm.EPMDocument' and 
document_content['isLatest'] == 'true':
        save_csv_record(document_content)
    document_content = {}
else:
    document_content[el.tag] = el.text.strip() if el.text else None
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and link.  I think I got it working a little better.  I still get a memory error, which I cannot understand.  The source file is 2GB and the output file dies at about 10 or 11 mb.  I am running an a win10 desktop with 32GB of RAM...I will keep trying to figure that out.  Nevertheless, thanks for the help.

Comment: I would guess that your xml file consists of numerous Document elements. If that's the case and you could post the first two or three *actual* Document elements I'd make an attempt at using iterparse on them.

Comment: Here are a few of the elements.

Comment: I updated the original post with my edited code and a few of the elements.  Could not paste it all in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Much simpler code.  I still get a Memory Error running the code.   It looks to get about 80% through the file (70M lines).  I did tweak one thing, I changed the one if statement: `if document_content['type']=='wt.epm.EPMDocument' and document_content['isLatest'] == 'true':`  I will keep playinng around with it.

Comment: Here is the actual error I am getting - `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PycharmProjects/windchill/stackOverflow.py", line 8, in <module>
    for ev, el in iterparse('windchill.xml'):
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1223, in iterator
MemoryError`